# unable to connect mongoDB and neo4j

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, connection

I'm following the steps provide at URL https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-doc-manager/ to connect mongoDb and neo4j.

1. In terminal started, mongod --replSet myDevReplSet
2. In new terminal started mongo shell, mongo
3. typed rs.initiate() in shell
4. Again in new  terminal typed,  mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:7474/db/data -d neo4j_doc_manager

But I get an error as:

> Exception in thread Thread-1:
>    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/gauravvashisth/anaconda/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914,
>   in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "/Users/gauravvashisth/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py",
>   line 104, in wrapped
>       func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/gauravvashisth/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py",
>   line 382, in run
>       self.update_version_from_client(self.main_conn)   File "/Users/gauravvashisth/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py",
>   line 334, in update_version_from_client
>       is_master = client.admin.command("isMaster")   File "/Users/gauravvashisth/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/database.py",
>   line 491, in command
>       with client._socket_for_reads(read_preference) as (sock_info, slave_ok):   File
>   "/Users/gauravvashisth/anaconda/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59,
>   in **enter**
>       return next(self.gen)   File "/Users/gauravvashisth/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py",
>   line 859, in _socket_for_reads
>       with self._get_socket(read_preference) as sock_info:   File "/Users/gauravvashisth/anaconda/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59,
>   in **enter**
>       return next(self.gen)   File "/Users/gauravvashisth/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py",
>   line 823, in _get_socket
>       server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)   File "/Users/gauravvashisth/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py",
>   line 214, in select_server
>       address))   File "/Users/gauravvashisth/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py",
>   line 189, in select_servers
>       self._error_message(selector))
>
> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members
>   match selector "Primary()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have at least one replicaset member in MongoDB.
You can query the members with rs.conf() command in mongo shell.
If it does not have a member, then you can do this:

```
    cfg = {
    ...     "_id" : "rs0",
    ...     "version" : 1,
    ...     "members" : [
    ...         {
    ...             "_id" : 0,
    ...             "host" : "localhost:27017"
    ...         }
    ...     ]
    ... }

    >rs.reconfig(cfg, {force:true})
```